# Generic Recursive Descent Parser for validating strings using Lex and C

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

Edited: Using Lex (flex) I need to write a recursive descent parser in C. The parser is going to read in an input that describes a NFA using a restricted context free grammar along with given one or more strings for validating. I need to read and store the NFA and then for each string, determine whether or not it is in the language. An example input file might look like:

```
A -> ab A1
A1-> ab A
A -> ε 
abab

aba
```

thus the parser should give following output:

```
Accept abab
Accept 
Reject aba
```

The grammar for the input files:

```
input --> grammar strings
grammar --> grammar production
         | production
production --> NT ARROW T NT EOL
         | NT ARROW NT EOL
         | NT ARROW EOL
strings --> strings string EOL
         | string EOL
string --> string T
         | /* epsilon */
```

I am not able to understand how can we make a parser using just Lex and C program that works on dynamic grammar meaning the code written should also work on other grammar.

Let's say for example accepting odd number of a's:

```
S -> 0  
S -> 1  
S -> 0 0 S 
S -> S 1 1
```

Comment: So you need to create a parser-generator like Yacc, but the generated parser should be recursive-decent instead of LALR? This has already been done. ;) I don't know the names of the top of my head, just that it has been done.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the context free grammars you have to accept? Are they, for example, restricted to being right regular?

Comment: No, there are no restrictions. If the grammar is left recursion then we need to automatically identify it and augment the grammar to remove left recursion / factorial.

Comment: Parsing the grammar grammar with a recursive descent parser is simple once the input has been tokenised; it looks like the expectation is that the lexer can distinguish `T` from `NT`, although you don't show the lexical rules. You don't even need recursive descent since there's no non-trivial recursion. Contrary to your response to my question, the grammars generated by that grammar grammar are all right-regular. You could easily put them into Greibach Normal Form, from which building an NFA is trivial. All of the necessary algos are simple...

Comment: ... and if you are using a standard textbook, you should find them all described there. If there is some detail about some algo you don't understand, feel free to write a much more specific question, which we'll attempt to answer.

Comment: By the way, the last two productions in your example are not derived from the grammar for grammars (which allows a maximum of two symbols on the RHS of a production). (And your description of the language it recognises is inaccurate).

Comment: To create a parser-generator you must first create a *parser*. Your parser should read and parse the input rule file. The parser needs to recognize the grammar of the rule file. As you parse each rule (`production` as you call them) you store information about the rule, like its name and a list of terminals and non-terminals. From this information you can then create the code to parse input using the rule, as outlined in my answer.

Comment: I also recommend you break down the program into smaller and simpler steps. Break each smaller step into even smaller and even simpler steps. And so on until nothing can be further broken apart. Then solve each little problem one by one. I suggest you start with the lexer for your parser-generator program, make it read the lexemes that will be in the input rule file, make it recognize and differ between terminals and non-terminals (`A` versus `a` for example). Then continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

As for a possible way to implement such a generator, would be to store a list of all rules.

Each rule have a list of its "dependencies". Like the rule `A` it would have two entries, one with the dependencies `ab` and `A1, and the other with an empty dependency list (meaning ε).

For the generation of the parser itself, you iterate over the (sorted) list of rules. When you reach `A` you program writes a function header to the destination source file.

For the `ab` and `A1` dependency chain, it then adds a check for the terminal `ab` and if it matches then it calls the function `A1` (which will be generated later).

Since there are two rules for `A`, your generator then creates an `else` for the second rule. Since it's ε the `else` branch just does nothing.

When there are no more rules for `A` then you end the function.

For the rule `A1` you do it similar: Create a function header, check for `ab` and if found call `A`. The difference is that here you can add an `else` which raises a syntax error.

The generated code written to the destination source file would then look something like this (with added function prototypes):

```
#include "my_parser_generator_functions.h"

void A(void);
void A1(void);

void A(void)
{
    if (match("ab"))
    {
        A1();
    }
    else
    {
        // ε
    }
}

void A1(void)
{
    if (match("ab"))
    {
        A();
    }
    else
    {
        syntax_error("Expected %s", "ab");
    }
}
```

---

Note that all this is just something I made up in the moment, I have never made a parser-generator (but I have made plenty of parsers, both Yacc/Bison based as well as recursive-decent).

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying but the problem I am facing here is to make a generic parser as in it should parse multiple grammar. Meaning a single code should work on a grammar generating "ab"* string / grammar generating odd number of 'a' strings and many other... The example you provided is restricted by a single grammar hence not generic.

Comment: @Orion The example I gave is what a compiler-generator could create for the grammar you show. So the question you ask isn't really about the generation of the recursive-decent parser but rather how to parse and handle the grammar input file? Please **edit** your question to elaborate and give more details.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thankyou so much for your input.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please let me know if any other clarification is needed.